# Azure SQL Database Deployment Time

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I've got a ~70 GB SQL database copy sitting in an Azure blob storage container that I'm in the middle of deploying to a Azure SQL database. We're now in the 35th hour of the deployment. For the size of my database, should I expect the deployment to take this long or is it likely that something's gone awry and I should start over?

Comment: what is the location of blob and database ?are both the same ?

Comment: Actually,it should not take this much time

Comment: I had my database set to the lowest possible DTU settings on the standard tier. Both the blob and the database are in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

You should start over. The worst performance I have seen is 6 to 7 GB throughput over 30 minutes.

Try other methods explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What tier database did you have?

Comment: I usually use Standard tiers.